# Is 長 in Japanese related to “naga” in Thai and Sanskrit?

Tags: etymology

The kanji 長い (“nagai”) means “long” in Japanese.

And “naga” in Sanskrit and Thai means “snake” or “serpent”.

It seems to me that there could be a relation between them given that snakes are usually described as long.

Is there any relationship between them? Do they have a shared origin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One could extend that hypothesis to ask if there's a connection between English *long* and Yiddish *schlong*.

- [English *long*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/long#Etymology_1) ultimately derives from Proto-Indo-European **dlongʰos* (“long”).
- [Yiddish *schlong*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%90%D6%B7%D7%A0%D7%92#Yiddish) is from German *Schlange* ("snake") and ultimately derives from Proto-Indo-European **slenk-* (“to wind, twist, slink, creep”).

That is, no apparent connection.

Back to your particular thought:

- [Japanese 長- *naga-*](http://gogen-allguide.com/na/nagai.html) is thought to derive from, or be cognate with, obsolete verb 流る *nagaru*, root of modern verb pair 流れる *nagareru* ("to flow") / 流す *nagasu* ("to flush something, to make something flow").  I've also thought these might be related to verb 投ぐ *nagu*, modern 投げる *nageru* ("to throw").
- [Sanskrit नाग *naga* ("snake")](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%97#Sanskrit) ultimately derives from Proto-Indo-European **sneg-* (“to crawl; a creeping thing”), the same as [English *snake*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snake#Etymology).

So again, no apparent connection.

Comment: @Fogmeister: Happy to help!  FWIW, some folks trace the Japanese term even earlier to reconstructed _*nanka-_.